# TypeError: This'VARIABLE_NAME' is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanna define  to null. Why won't it let me do this? I'm getting a TypeError error. I think there was no such problem with older versions?I want to treat this variable like typescript?

```
unsubscribe: null ;

componentDidMount() {          
    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
        })

}

componentWillUnMount() {   // EDITED
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillMount` gets called **before** `componentDidMount` - this is a typo. You meant to write unsubscribe in `componentWillUnmount`, not `componentWillMount`

Comment: Yes thanks. but still  I get an error on this line ( unsubscribe: null ;). did not change the situation. What can I write instead of if we can no longer make such a demonstration?

Comment: @cantaş `unsubscribe = null`